# Phonegap How to make android build

Tags: android, cordova

I have created a build in ios successfully. Now i am trying to make build in android.
I have added android platform and imported this in eclise(ADT). I want to make configuration for android, as i am new to mobile application. I am unable to find any good reference for building android tutorial. I looked into getting started tutorial of phonegap but it was not much helpful

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using Cordova 3.0 and CLI

Proceed as following (some steps you might have already done, for completeness, I list them here anyway)

1. Open *Eclipse ADT -> Window -> Android SDK Manager* and make sure you have at least the 'Android SDK Tools', 'Android SDK Platform-tools' and at least on API installed.
2. Add the 'android sdk tools' and 'android sdk platform-tools' to your path.
3. In your cordova app (e.g. /myApp) folder, execute `$cordova platform add android`
4. Im assuming you have all your jscode correctly bundled in the /myApp/www folder, as you already have a working ios build. Otherwise, do so.
5. Plug in your Android Device or create and start a new AVD (In Eclipse: *Window -> 'Android Virtual device manager'*).
6. execute `$cordova prepare android`
7. Open Eclipse and then *File -> Import -> Android/Existing Code Into Workspace*. In the opening 'Import Projects'-Window, select your /myApp/platforms/android as root directory. Depending on your workspace, you must select 'Copy projects into workspace', however your workspace would better already include the project, as this saves you from importing a new project after every $cordova prepare statement
8. In Eclipse: *Run -> Run Configurations -> Target*:: Enter Your settings depending on wether you use AVD or not.
9. On the bottom right: Run. Your app will be built and run.

Notes:

- If you use mulitple platforms (e.g. android and ios), this way is more preferable than the way of user1306579, where you copy/hardlink your code directly in the /myApp/platforms/android/ folder, as you would have to do this for every platfrom equally and even worse: If you run $cordova prepare (or any command containg this, as $cordova run, $cordova build, ...) you would loose your changes.
- **Never edit JavaScript-Code directly in your */myApp/platforms/(anyplatform)/www/* folder**. Always use */myApp/www/* and run `$cordova prepare` afterwards...
- After step 5 you could use `$cordova emulate android` (for your avd) or `cordova run android` (real device), which would replace all other steps. However, if there are errors coming up, finding the reasons might be more difficult.
- If your questions was over how to configurate the android app (platform merges, manifest configurations, ...) feel free to ask again :)

Regards, miweiss

Answer (score 0):

I builded phonegap application with ant.
I think that this is not a big deal to build it with eclipse. You should copy web resources to the platforms/android/assets/www folder. Then you should use platforms/android as your project folder. I think you can use symbolic or hard links instead of copying to always refer to actual data.