# Error in installation/Building of Phonegap

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am new to phonegap. I already have ADT in my PC.

1)I installed NodeJs.

2)I wrote on cmd

npm install -g phonegap

phonegap create my-app

cd my-app

phonegap run android

```
[phonegap]detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] No platforms added to this project. Please use 'cordova platform add <platform>'.
```

Here I already set the correct PATH. But the same problem occurring. If anyone knows plz let me know.
Thnx

Still not working .. Can anybody knows this .. Plz .. Thanks in advance..

I added these  path for android: -

D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools\

D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools\

and Java path is already set here.. So What's the problem here.. anyone can give the solution plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I got the solution

Initially I wrote the command  `cordova platform add android`, Then it was showing the error :

```
No platforms added to this project. Please use 'cordova platform add <platform>'.
```

I did some changes:

- I change it to `cordova -d platform add android`
- I reset all path, reset means again set my JAVA_HOME path and ANT_HOME path and then I gave the command `cordova -d platform add android`
- then it was again showing error like `There is no script engine for file extension .js`. Then just use the command in commmand prompt `assoc .js=JSFILE` and put the command on prompt `cordova -d platform add android` and its done, now it contains android folder within platforms.

Thank You All for help

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: THIS ANSWER USES CORDOVA, NOT PHONEGAP**

You must tell cordova which platforms you are going to use (e.g. android)

therefore, before executing command `$cordova run android` you must (once) execute `cordova platform add android`

For more details, see my answer here: [Phonegap How to make android build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630533/phonegap-how-to-make-android-build/18652507#18652507)

Regards, miweiss

Comment: @ShyamDixit: I just realized that you're using phonegap and not cordova. Therefore, my answer indeed might not be very helpful ;)

Comment: You might want to try `phonegap help` to see which platforms are installed. Also you should think about switching to Cordova, if you just started and if you are not interested in remote build - it's a bit less confusing...

Answer (score 0):

For Mac
just add the cordova path :

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/bin:/usr/local/bin

now add platform like :
cordova platform add android

the platform will be added.