# Android - ionic - no platforms added to this project

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have successfully executed the following commands

```
$ npm install -g cordova
$ npm install -g ionic
$ ionic start myApp blank
$ cd myApp
$ ionic platform add android
```

**But the next command is not working**

```
$ ionic build android
```

when I execute the command, I see an error ie "**No platforms added to this project. Please use 'cordova platform add platform'**"

please help me with your suggestions, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in installation/Building of Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652164/error-in-installation-building-of-phonegap)

Comment: I followed, but still not working

Comment: I am using windows 7, I installed android SDK and jdk

Comment: fo you get any error while add platform with command 'ionic platform add android' if yes please mentioned error and if you don't get error please try to fire 'cordova platform ls' for checking which platform is installed and which can be installed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

please do following:

> 1. npm install -g cordova
> 2. npm install -g ionic
> 3. ionic start myApp blank
> 4. cd myApp
> 5. cordova platform add android

you can use cordova while installing platform in ionic project because Ionic internally use cordova itself.

Please feedback me if error still persist.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform rm android

cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

// edit

to execute these commands, you have to be in your root folder (where you have your config.xml)

Answer (score 3):

use this command before you build `cordova platform add android`.
enjoy your code time.

Comment: `cordova` and `ionic` if installed this is the solution. Thanks it works